# Adding cocoapods into my PodFile

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, podfile

I am working on an app, which requires cocoapods. In the manual of this app is written

> Add this to your Podfile:

```
pod 'SwiftSocket'
```

> And run then pod install

But when I make a pod file using `pod init` into my folder and then `open -a Xcode Podfile` and there I add lines

```
target 'SwiftSocket' do
pod 'SwiftSocket'
end
```

and the last `pod install` it says me an error

> Unable to find a target named `SwiftSocket`, did find `SwiftSocket iOS`, `SwiftSocket macOS`, `SwiftSocket tvOS`, and `iOS Example`.

Edit____________

Picture of my folder.

[image: Picture of my folder]

and how looks my Podfile now 
[image]

Comment: How your target app is called? check the target name should be your project target name

Comment: what is your project name ?

Comment: its called SwiftSocket

Comment: maybe that is your issue, try with another different name for your project @Josef

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is working perfectly, check out my podfile

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'Demo' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

pod 'SwiftSocket'

  # Pods for Demo

end
```

`Demo` is the project name. *Target name* will be your *project name*.

Comment: it is working, there is some issue from your end, please double check or create new project and try and what is SwiftSocket.podspec?

Comment: Stupid mistake, I have written wrong project name, thanks for help

Comment: @Josef let me know if I can help you in other queries